# Unity find the centre point selected circle segment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a dial that I mouse drag to rotate. I use `transform.rotation = finalRotation;` inside `public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)` to rotate the dial.

I want to divide the dial into 28 segments and when the user lets go of the mouse I want to move the dial to the centre of that segment.

the centre degrees of the segments are

Segment Positions: [
        0, 12, 25, 37.5, 50, 62.3,
        75.35, 88.5, 100.8, 114, 127, 140,
        153, 166.5, 180, 193, 206, 219,
        232, 245, 258.2, 271.4, 283.8,
        297, 309.5, 322, 334.2, 347 ]

So for example if I move the dial to `transform.rotation.z` of 10 then dial will be set to the first segment so I would snap the position to centre mark which is 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the segment positions you want to snap to in an array then loop through this using LINQ and put this in a method that returns the closest segment that you call when your drag ends.

```cs
using System.Linq; //don't forget to include LINQ

//Define the points you want to snap to
float[] segmentPositions = new float[28] { 0f, 12f, 25f, 37.5f, 50f, 62.3f, 75.35f, 88.5f, 100.8f, 114f, 127f,
                                        140f, 153f, 166.5f, 180f, 193f, 206f, 219f, 232f, 245f, 258.2f, 271.4f,
                                        283.8f, 297f, 309.5f, 322f, 334.2f, 347f };

void Start()
{
    //Get the closest segment based on the current z rotation
    //rotation.z is in radians. Since we defined our snapping points in degrees we need to 
    //convert using Matf.Rad2Deg.
    var newZRotation = GetClosestSegment(transform.rotation.z * Mathf.Rad2Deg); 

    //Alternatively we can pass in the localEulerAngles instead
    var newZRotation = GetClosestSegment(transform.localEulerAngles.z);
    //Apply the z rotation to your object here
}

private float GetClosestSegment(float input)
{
    //Get the closest point inside segmentPositions and return it
    return segmentPositions.OrderBy(s => Mathf.Abs(s - input)).First();
}
```

Note that this will throw a null reference if the Array is empty. so if you can't guarantee that the array is always filled make sure you perform a null check

Comment: I think you could simply use `First` here ... if there are elements in this array they will always have valid values (`float` has always a default value of `0`)

Comment: thanks for this, unfortunately I only get 0 returned now matter what `transform.rotation.z`

Comment: @KeithPower are your sure the `transform.rotation.z` you are supplying isn't empty then? To test it out try giving it a static number like `GetClosestSegment(10)` it should return 12. Keep in mind that it sends the z value of the object this script it attached to. If that isn't the object you want to rotate make sure you give the z rotation of the rotating object https://gyazo.com/056a514975d5d3a02c20f6722c89b0e5

Comment: definitely getting values for `transform.rotation.z` such as 0.1048443. I tried passing in `GetClosestSegment(10)` and did indeed get 12

Comment: @KeithPower Well 0.104 is closest to 0, so it makes sense that it returns 0. It may be that it is using radians instead of degrees (the snapping points are defined in degrees) 0.104 radians is about 5.95 degrees. Try passing `transform.rotation.z *  Mathf.Rad2Deg` (radians to degrees) or using `GetClosestSegment(transform.localEulerAngles.z)` since eulerAngles should be in degrees

Comment: @KeithPower glad it helped. I've updated the answer to reflect the radians/degrees part better